# Change format String android

Tags: android, date, date-formatting

I use database in my app.

I have datepickers where I store the chosen date as a String and save it as "yyyy-MM-dd". I have a TextView where I show the chosen data but I want to show it as "dd.MM.yyyy". How can I do that?

For Example:

To convert 2017-05-08 into 08.05.2017

Comment: what you tried so far ??

Comment: Does `SimpleDateFormat` tell you anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String mainString="2017-05-08";
String[] separated = CurrentString.split("-");
```

Now your new String will like this:

```
String mainString="2017-05-08";
        String[] separated = mainString.split("-");

        String newString="";
        for(int index=separated.length-1;index>=0;index--){
            newString=newString+""+separated[index]+".";
        }
        newString=newString.split(0,newString.length()-1);
```

Here is the sample output `08.05.2017`

Comment: i get a OutOfBoundsException when i do the 3rd line of code u gave me..

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat srcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat dstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date date = srcFormat.parse("2017-05-08");
String result = dstFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-05-08");
textView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String date = getConvertDate("yyyy-MM-dd","dd.MM.yyyy","2017-05-08");
```

getConvertDate method

```
public static String getConvertDate(String sourceFormat, String destFormat, String strDate) {
        String finalDate = "";
        try {

            DateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceFormat);
            // parse the date string into Date object
            Date date = srcDf.parse(strDate);
            DateFormat destDf = new SimpleDateFormat(destFormat);
            // format the date into another format
            finalDate = destDf.format(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalDate;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static String getFormattedDate(String date){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date1 = null;
    Calendar temp = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        date1 = dateFormat.parse(date);
        temp.setTime(date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    return newFormat.format(date1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
String date = null;
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        try {
            Date convertedDate = inputFormat.parse(selectdate);
            date = d.format(convertedDate);
            Log.e("Check Value", "Check Value" + date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code and reuse it anywhere:

**DateConv.java**

```
 public static String convertIntoDateFormat( String aSelectedDate, String aConversionFormat, String aCurrentFormat ) {
 if( aSelectedDate.length () == 0 ) return "";

 String aDate = "";

try {
  DateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat ( aCurrentFormat );
  Date dateObj = null;
  try {
    dateObj = curFormater.parse ( aSelectedDate.toString () );
  } catch( ParseException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
    Log.e ( TAG, e.getMessage ().toString () );
  }

  DateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat ( aConversionFormat );
  aDate = postFormater.format ( dateObj );
} catch( Exception e ) {
  e.printStackTrace ();
}

return aDate;
}
```

Pass your Current date format and required date format here:

```
aCurrentDate = DateConv.convertIntoDateFormat(aData[i], "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily show date format as you described . Follow these two steps : 
1) Convert String date into date variable by parsing it into "yyyy-MM-dd" format .
2) Now convert above output date to format "dd.MM.yyyy".

Example :

```
Date String2date,TextViewDate;

        SimpleDateFormat DB_dateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        String2date = DB_dateFormate.parse(DB_date);


        SimpleDateFormat TextViewDateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

        TextViewDate = TextViewDateFormate.format(String2date);
        Log.d("OutPut Date :: ", TextViewDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the conversion can be done completely within SQLite itself:

```
select strftime('%d.%m.%Y', date);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace "-" to "." if you need to set in a single TextView like,

```
String newDate = oldDateString.replace("-", ".");
```

To change order you can use split option,

```
String[] dates = oldDateString.split("-"); // here, dates[0] is year, dates[1] is month and dates[2] is day
```

Now,

```
String newDate = dates[2] + "." + dates[1] + "." + dates[0]
```

Or change formatting,

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

try {
      Date date = formatter.parse(oldDateString);
      newDate = formatter.format(date);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: and how do I change the order ? Because the day must come at the beginning now and not at the end